# Why does CodeMirror not work on Ipad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, codemirror

Greetings,

http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/jstest.html works on Safari on PC, but not on an Ipad. Which is a shame, since I wanted to use it for an app. My question is not only why does it not work, but how should I go about analyzing things that break on Ipad Safari ?

T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor in CodeMirror is actually an iframe, and not a native text input form element. The problem here I suspect is that the browser on the iPad does not know if the keyboard should be activated because some DOM element has key events bound to it.

To do that, Safari would have to analyze the source code to deduce key bindings and when should the keyboard be activated - which sound hugely problematic to me.

Comment: Codemirror 2.0 abandoned the iframe and support for IE6 quirks mode.

Answer (score 6):

CodeMirror2 works mostly fine on an iPad;

You can add text, remove text and move the cursor around. 
You can however not hilite words and cut / copy / paste (as of today 2012-06-27).

Comment: How to fix Copy&Paste functionality?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it used an iframe in the past, but I have codemirror on my website now and I see no iframes at all contained inside it.

this is almost one year later though, so perhaps now the situation has changed.